# How to find the number of valence electrons with the help of quantum numbers?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

I'm bit confused on how to find the number of valence electrons. For example, Boron ($\ce{B) has the electronic configuration as: $\mathrm{1s^2 2s^2 2p^1}$. So what would be its number of valence electrons : 1 or 3. According to me the answer should the 1 as the last orbital ($\mathrm{p}$ orbital) has 1 electron. Am I wrong? Please guide me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any electrons present in the electron configuration of the element in question, but not present in the nearest noble gas with an atomic number below that of the element, is a valence electron.

Comment: Not quite correct. For example  manganese (Mn) has configuration $\ce{[Ar]\ 4s^2\ 3d^5}$ and hence 7 valence electrons.

Comment: Fair point @MaxW, I will edit.

Comment: I'd use the KISS principle here. // The valence electrons are the electrons that can participate in bonding. For n=2 there can be $\ce{sp^3}$ hybridization so all the 2s and 2p electrons are valence electrons. // If you want to elaborate more certainly some paragraphs would help.